# Profile2 template for profile type?

Tags: theming, users

I have alredy created profile2 type with machine name "user" and now i would to overide template, can someone explain me how i have to name my new tpl? i ve copied existing, and tried some rename variants, but i didnt find solution.

In google i didnt find solution too.

Here is link for module https://drupal.org/project/profile2

Answer (score 1):

To theme a custom template for profile2, try the following:

- copy profile2.tpl.php from your module folder, to your theme's template folder
- rename the file profile2--machine_name.tpl.php (profile2--user.tpl.php)
- adjust the template as desired
- clear the cache

Comment: I tried this variant before question, but now i found my problem. Profile machine name cant "user", becouse on this machine name doesnt work any tpl (aslo globaly profile2.tpl,php).